# thinkpad fan never turns off after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend, wayland, thinkpad, fan

I have a T470s running Arch linux with wayland, kernel `Linux 4.16.7-1-ARCH`

After suspend and resume, the fan runs and runs and runs ... and never turns off. The problem is described in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T470s#kernel_and_hardware_support), however they don't say how to solve it.

Someone suggested that upgrading the kernel may help, however, 4.16 is pretty recent. I don't want to replace wayland by xorg.

Related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1480844

Answer (score 0):

Updating UEFI/BIOS solved the issue.